# Set a hyperlink depending on a chechbox

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

In my code below , I have two columns B and C where B is a column of check-boxes and C is a blank column .

When the checkbox in column B is checked (TRUE) , I want to put a hyperlink to the next cell in C but it didn't work ..

And how can I check one check box at a time so if I checked a new one the previous got unchecked ?

This is my code

```
var hasValue = sheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < hasValue.length; i++) {
    if (hasValue[i][0] == "TRUE") {
        var cell2hyperlink = sheet.getRange(i, 3, 1, 1);
        cell2hyperlink.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com","google")')
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that the first modification points are as follows. 1. When you want to compare the boolean, please use ``true`` and modify to ``if (hasValue[i][0] == true) {``. The reason of ``it didn't work ..`` might be this. 2. By the modification of 1, when ``sheet.getRange(i, 3, 1, 1);`` is run under the condition that "B2" is checked, an error occurs here because ``i`` is 0. Start of the range is 1. And then, can I ask you about your question? What is the meaning of ``the next cell in C ``?

Comment: Are you running this using an `onEdit` trigger or from some one-time or adhoc function?

Comment: @HenriqueG.Abreu onEdit ?

Comment: @Tanaike the next cell means the cell in the same row but in column  C not B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions made by @Tanaike , here is the answer.

I also made an (else) case to undo and empty the cell when the checkbox is unchecked.

```
var hasValue = sheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < hasValue.length; i++) {
    if (hasValue[i][0] == true) {
        var cell2hyperlink = sheet.getRange(i+2, 3, 1, 1);
        cell2hyperlink.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("https:www.google.com//","google")')
    }
    if (hasValue[i][0] == false) {
        var cell2hyperlink = sheet.getRange(i+2, 3, 1, 1).setValue('');  
    }
}
```

Comment: Yet  I didn't how to allow only one checkbox to be checked and if a new checkbox is checked , the old one becomes unchecked.